# How do I set ComboBoxColumn in edit mode with one click

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, triggers, styles

I'm trying to skip one additional click in DataGrid for selecting comboBox items. By default you need 3 clicks: focus cell -> Edite mode -> Pull list.

This code:

```
               <DataGridComboBoxColumn.CellStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="IsEditing" Value="True" />                                    
                            </Trigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>                            
                    </Style>
                </DataGridComboBoxColumn.CellStyle>
```

It's working for me, but only one time for each column cell. First time its working fine, then if i click somewhere else and click on the same cell, i need 3 clicks like default.

Some notes:
i tried this variant:

```
<Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="True">
    <Setter Property="IsEditing" Value="True" />
</Trigger>
```

but it messes up my binding scheme (it doesn't pull comboBox Item list).

Also I am using this code in other places:

```
<Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
    <Setter Property="IsEditing" Value="True" />
</Trigger>
```

but it pull list in one click, and in some cases i don't want it.

Answer (score 0):

well when I had this issue, I replaced combobox column with template column and set cell template to combobox.

And then I realised that it is far more easier to deal with template column with combobox in it rather than to have comboboxColumn

Comment: Thank you for answer, but i don't feel like changing my dataGrid now, nor i need this change so much. Maybe someone will know, why this trigger happening only once. I will look to cell templates in the futurefor new DataGrid's

Comment: yea sure, please post answer if you find that thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Probably you checked this already, but are the "IsEditing" resetted after clicking another item? Maybe add the default to be actually false?